# how to add youtube plugin to ckeditor

Tags: php

> My CKEditor confiq.js as follows :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        config.toolbarGroups = [
            { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
            { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
            { name: 'links' },
            { name: 'insert' },
            { name: 'forms' },
            { name: 'tools' },
            { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
            { name: 'others' },
            '/',
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
            { name: 'styles' },
            { name: 'colors' },
            { name: 'about' }
        ];
        config.extraPlugins = 'imageuploader';
        config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
        config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
        config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
         };
```

> I want add youtube url and get youtube vedio.please help me

Comment: what brooo. i am beginer to php .this is for my accadamic project i am not developer .@Akin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Download YouTube plugin in compressed format from the [CkEditor official page](http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube).
2. Extract the downloaded file into the CKEditor’s plugins folder.
3. Addconfig.extraPlugins = 'youtube'; in your configuration (config.js).

confiq.js code like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
        config.toolbarGroups = [
            { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
            { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
            { name: 'links' },
            { name: 'insert' },
            { name: 'forms' },
            { name: 'tools' },
            { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
            { name: 'others' },
            '/',
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
            { name: 'styles' },
            { name: 'colors' },
            { name: 'about' }
        ];
        config.extraPlugins = 'imageuploader';
        config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
        config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
        config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
        config.extraPlugins = 'youtube';
        config.youtube_width = '640';
        config.youtube_height = '480';
        config.youtube_responsive = true;
        config.youtube_older = false;
        config.youtube_related = true;
        config.youtube_autoplay = false;
        config.youtube_controls = true;
        config.youtube_privacy = false;
};
```

Comment: Its very simple and its very clearly given in the http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube .so go through this link.